# about permssion

Tags: permissions

I am really new to ubuntu (12.04) to automount my drive I added this line to `fstab`

`/dev/sda4   /media/FF15-ED92  vfat    defaults    0   0`

But now when I want to delete a directory or a file it doesn't delete like using del key of keyboard
so right clicked on that directories and files but there was no option to delete and move to trash was also not clickable.
So how can I give myself permissions to do this.
Also I can't do this on my pen drive also.

I tried this but nothing happened

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/44gb
```

if I change from chmod to chown then it gives that

changing ownership of `/media/44gb: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 3):

You need to not only set the owner and permissions on the directory where you mount the drive, but you also need to set mounting options in fstab.

I use the preferred method of UUIDs rather than your older method of /dev/sda.  If you want to use this, it tells you how at the top of fstab, but at a terminal, you enter the command `sudo blkid` to get a list of UUIDs, which you can then cut and paste into fstab.

My NTFS drive is set with these options; I am the owner:

```
#sdax good idea to add comment here
UUID=C61460BE1460B2DB  /mnt/foldername  ntfs-3g auto,users,uid=yourID,gid=yourID,utf8,dmask=002,fmask=113  0  0
```

I mount it in /mnt/foldername, and yourID should be changed to your login name.  This should get you started, but if it isn't quite right, you can either learn more by searching, or by asking here.

I don't actually have any FAT/FAT32/VFAT partition, but I think they may be the same, except for the ntfs-3g part.

the /media directory is traditionally used for auto-mounted media, I think, but I suppose it's OK. I use /mnt.

**Edit - testing mount options**

One easy method for testing and debugging the options in /etc/fstab is to use a special mount command that will mount all the usual mounts in fstab interactively, rather than at boot time.

My method is to keep open the file `/etc/fstab`, but save any edits; then, at a command prompt, I enter `sudo mount -a` to mount everything in fstab, and it will output an error message if there are any problems.  If there are no problems, I test to see if the results are what I want.  If not, I unmount that directory only, using `sudo umount /path/mountname`, make another edit to fstab, save, and repeat until it's working.

If there is a syntax error, then before closing the file, I usually comment out the entry if I can't get it fixed, and try again later.

Comment: thanks guys for your help but i converted it from vfat to ntfs

Comment: Good idea.  ntfs is more robust than vfat.

Comment: yeah it is now working good but i will really try uid and gid thing
actually i firstly tried UUID one only but there was some problem in that command and it was not getting mounted on startup.
I was in a hurry so i used dev/sda method

Comment: I added an Edit to my answer with a testing/debugging tip you might find helpful while working this out.

Comment: I found my mistake.
I was using `ntfs` instead of `ntfs-3g`
as for ntfs linux gives read only permission.